# jQuery .next() Is Going Onto Incorect Div(S)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This basic snippet of code was written to change the classes of indexed divs. Specificaly the div with the class .primaryCategory . Now the function works great, it goes .next() and .prev() when you click on the correct arrow, but when you go next over 3 times (since there are only 3 divs present in this case) it moves on to the arrow divider. (as in .primaryCategory-leftArrow only, once it switches onto the divider (which its not supposed to) the left/previous arrow will not go to the previous anymore.

So basically what I am asking is how can I make it so that the next/right arrow will not go on to .primaryCategory-leftArrow

**JavaScript / jQuery Code Snippet**

```
$(".wrapper .primaryCategory-wrapper .primaryCategory-RightArrow").bind(eventtype, function(e) {
    if($("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").is(":last-child")){
        // do nothing
    }else {
        $("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").removeClass("primaryCategory-active").next().addClass("primaryCategory-active");
    }
});

$(".wrapper .primaryCategory-wrapper .primaryCategory-leftArrow").bind(eventtype, function(e) {
    if($("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").is(":first-child")){
        // do nothing
    }else {
        $("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").removeClass("primaryCategory-active").prev().addClass("primaryCategory-active");
    }
});
```

**HTML CODE Snippet**

```
        <div class="primaryCategory-wrapper">
            <!-- Single Primary Category -->
            <div class="primaryCategory">
                <!-- Primary Category Icon -->
                <img class="primaryCategory-icon" alt="primaryCategory" src="img/placeholder/primaryCategoryIcon-320x320.png">
                <!-- Primary Category Heading -->
                <h1>Lorium</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- Single Primary Category -->
            <div class="primaryCategory">
                <!-- Primary Category Icon -->
                <img class="primaryCategory-icon" alt="primaryCategory" src="img/placeholder/primaryCategoryIcon-320x320.png">
                <!-- Primary Category Heading -->
                <h1>Lorium</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- Single Primary Category -->
            <div class="primaryCategory">
                <!-- Primary Category Icon -->
                <img class="primaryCategory-icon" alt="primaryCategory" src="img/placeholder/primaryCategoryIcon-320x320.png">
                <!-- Primary Category Heading -->
                <h1>Lorium</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="primaryCategory-leftArrow"><!-- Left Primary Arrow (Mobile) --></div>
            <div class="primaryCategory-RightArrow"><!-- Right Primary Arrow (Mobile) --></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `.primaryCategory-leftArrow` and `.primaryCategory-RightArrow` is on the same parent element of your `.primaryCategory`, they are all siblings.

To fix this you can move your `.primaryCategory-leftArrow` and `.primaryCategory-RightArrow` from your `.primaryCategory-wrapper`.

Or you can specify a selector on your `.next('selector')`, like this:

```
$("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").removeClass("primaryCategory-active").next(".primaryCategory").addClass("primaryCategory-active");
```

This will only retrieve the next sibling with a `primaryCategory` class.

---

But clicking the right arrow more than 3 times will lose the active class

You need to add a condition to fix this, here is a better solution:

```
$(".primaryCategory-wrapper .primaryCategory-RightArrow").bind("click", function(e) {

    if(!$("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").is("div.primaryCategory:last")){
        $("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").removeClass("primaryCategory-active").next().addClass("primaryCategory-active");
    }
});

$(".primaryCategory-wrapper .primaryCategory-leftArrow").bind("click", function(e) {
    if(!$("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").is("div.primaryCategory:first")){
        $("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").removeClass("primaryCategory-active").prev().addClass("primaryCategory-active");
    }
});
```

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/cucLB/)

Comment: Huge thanks, I ended up using both of your answers suggestions! Good thinking!

Comment: Actually, after doing this when clicking on the right arrow more than 3 times it marks all as inactive and you cannot go back. And it doesnt seem to add active to any other classes. No errors in js console either.

Comment: Hi Kevin I've updated my answer base on your comment. You need a condition to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens because the `leftArrow` and `RightArrow` are wrapped at the same level of the other `<div>` elements. You could either refine the wrapping around the tags labeled as `<!-- Single Primary Category -->` or moving the arrow elements one level above:

**HTML**

```
<div class="primaryCategory-wrapper">
    <div class="primaryCategory-subwrapper">
        <!-- Single Primary Category -->
        <div class="primaryCategory">
        <!-- Primary Category Icon -->
            <img class="primaryCategory-icon" alt="primaryCategory" src="img/placeholder/primaryCategoryIcon-320x320.png">
            <!-- Primary Category Heading -->
            <h1>Lorium</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Single Primary Category -->
        <div class="primaryCategory">
            <!-- Primary Category Icon -->
            <img class="primaryCategory-icon" alt="primaryCategory" src="img/placeholder/primaryCategoryIcon-320x320.png">
            <!-- Primary Category Heading -->
            <h1>Lorium</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Single Primary Category -->
        <div class="primaryCategory">
            <!-- Primary Category Icon -->
            <img class="primaryCategory-icon" alt="primaryCategory" src="img/placeholder/primaryCategoryIcon-320x320.png">
            <!-- Primary Category Heading -->
            <h1>Lorium</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="primaryCategory-leftArrow"><!-- Left Primary Arrow (Mobile) --></div>
        <div class="primaryCategory-RightArrow"><!-- Right Primary Arrow (Mobile) --></div>
</div>
```

Also you should reestructure your conditional clauses so you don't get an empty if

**JavaScript**

```
$(".wrapper .primaryCategory-wrapper .primaryCategory-RightArrow").bind(eventtype, function(e) {
    if(!($("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").is(":last-child"))) {
        $("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").removeClass("primaryCategory-active").next().addClass("primaryCategory-active");
    }
});

$(".wrapper .primaryCategory-wrapper .primaryCategory-leftArrow").bind(eventtype, function(e) {
    if(!($("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").is(":first-child"))) {
        $("div.primaryCategory.primaryCategory-active").removeClass("primaryCategory-active").prev().addClass("primaryCategory-active");
    }
});
```